# Unable to install the iron version of ROS 2

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, ros-iron

I am trying to install the ROS 2, iron version on my Ubuntu 22.04.06 version. I am following the official documentation on the website for the installation - [ROS 2 Iron Installation documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html).

However, I get the error - `E: Unable to locate package ros-iron-desktop`, as soon as I give the command `sudo apt install ros-iron-desktop`. I was getting the same error as I tried to install the humble version.

Others who had faced the same problem solved it by switching to 22.04 version of Ubuntu, I however am using the same, so that wasn't the main issue I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running a compatible OS, this generally means that you have not [enabled the required repositories](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html#enable-required-repositories) or that you have not updated your cache after adding the required repositories (accomplished by running `sudo apt update`). If you did run those commands then go back and confirm that there were no typos or errors.

Comment: I did give those commands. In fact executed every line of command as given in the documentation. For verification, I try follow the same procedure on my other laptop, but still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove source list with the command below and reinstall again

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt autoremove
# Consider upgrading for packages previously shadowed.
sudo apt upgrade
```